# what packages should I install in ubuntu 12.04 to fulfill opengl requirements for using nouveau driver?

Tags: nvidia, opengl, nouveau, mesa

I try to switch from nvidia to nouveau driver via script:

## !/bin/bash

stop gdm

rmmod nvidia

sed -i "s/nouveau/nvidia/" /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf

update-alternatives --set gl_conf /usr/lib/mesa/ld.so.conf
ldconfig

modprobe nouveau

cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf{.nouveau,}

start gdm

and driver is loaded and X started but compiz it doesn't. In .xsession-errors
I see:

Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Root visual is not a GL visual
compiz (opengl) - Error: initScreen failed
compiz (core) - Error: Couldn't activate plugin 'opengl'
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Root visual is not a GL visual
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Root visual is not a GL visual
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Root visual is not a GL visual
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Root visual is not a GL visual
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Root visual is not a GL visual
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Root visual is not a GL visual
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Root visual is not a GL visual
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: Root visual is not a GL visual
gnome-session[19075]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
gnome-session[19075]: WARNING: Application 'compiz.desktop' killed by signal
gnome-session[19075]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly

what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: I found solution by myself!! :-) I missed: libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution by myself!! :-) I missed: libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental